# How to create Doughnut Chart using Infragistics and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, infragistics, ignite-ui

I'am create a web site using AngularJS Framework, I want create a Doughnut Chart usign Infragistics, I found igniteui-angular but no look any directive for Doughnut chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the Ignite UI widgets are initialized in similar ways. Here you can find more information on how to create them - https://github.com/IgniteUI/igniteui-angular#initializing-controls.

Here's how to create igDoughnutChart using the controller options:

```
<div id="chart1" data-ig-doughnut-chart="opts">
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dkamburov/baz197ep/1/).

Comment: With this solution I can't get it to refresh the chart datasource as the angular model changes. Is it possible to get that to work?

Comment: Have you tried setting opts = newOpts; where the newOpts are containing the new refreshed dataSource?

Comment: Yes that was my last resort. Would be much better if we could update datasource and it would reflect in the chart (binding), instead of manually redrawing the chart every time datasource is changed

Comment: I encourage you to log an issue in [igniteui-angular repo](https://github.com/IgniteUI/igniteui-angular/issues) to improve the binding capabilities of igDoughnutChart. I saw it's done for igDataChart so it should be possible for the igDoughnutChart too.